# Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, mime-types

When loading my page I get this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream
```

My page is loading jpeg images. The server writes the images bytes to an output stream ans sends it to the client.

What do I have to do to prevent this warning?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set the correct Mime type.
Set the correct `Content-Type` http header for the image.
For instance a jpeg image will have `Content-Type: image/jpeg`